# Push middle column to top on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns in a row. The middle column needs to be on top on small screens with the left and then the right below it. I.E. large screen 1 2 3, small screens 2 1 3. I couldn't get this code, found on similar question, to work.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
    2
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
    1
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    3
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
     2
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
     1
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
     3
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same as the previous response which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works flawlessly.

```
    <div class="container text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 push-md-3">
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    1
</div></div>

<div class="col-md-3 pull-md-6">
<div class="alert alert-info">
    2
</div></div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="alert alert-success">
    3
</div>
</div></div></div>
```